# How to unsbscribe from the FirebaseMsgService to stop getting notifications

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I have created a `MyFirebaseMsgService` to receive Push notification from my Azure notification Hub following the various blogs to get everything working. my resultant service looks as below:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    NotificationHub hub;
    //override on
    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "FCM token: " + token);
        SendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        // Register with Notification Hubs
        hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.NotificationHubListenConnectionString, this);

        var tags = new List<string>() { };
        var regID = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;

        Log.Debug(TAG, $"Successful registration of ID {regID}");
    }
    public async override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
```

so far so good, its all working fine, but now the challange I have is, I want the user to have control over stopping / starting the notification subscription.

right now once the subscription is created, I think its somehow running in the background and this class is out of reach from my application to do anything with the `NotificationHub` instance there. I don't see `OnNewToken` being ever called after the 1st time no matter howmany times I restart the app on the phone.

can some one please suggest me how I can enable/disable the subscription to the messages from the server. almost all the resources on net talsk about using `Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.Instance.UnsubscribeFromTopic()` which is not helping me.

I am only targeting on Android, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me brief it to you, Firebase recommends that you use data push rather than notification push if you want to have complete control over push notifications.

When you check their [official documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) it says:

> Use notifications when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want your app to handle the display or process the messages on your Android client app...

So what this basically means is change the body of your notifications to something like

```
{
 "data": {
   "type" : "mytype",
   "title": "My Title",
   "body": "My Notification Message"
  },
 "to": "/topics/all"
}
```

Once you do that it will always call your `OnMessageReceived` method where you can handle whether or not the notification needs to be shown to the user.